# Sum of the Volumes of Two Tetrahedra Obtained by Reflection Equals the Volume of the Reference Tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have recently published a note in the [International Journal of Computer Discovered Mathematics](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vHtFzeEq0vu3kdrnqAHqN2lD5krxLKk5/view) where I prove a conjecture by Van Khea. The result is as follows:

**Theorem (Van Khea)**: Let $ABC$ be a triangle, and $P$ any point on the plane of $ABC$. Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be arbitrary points on sides $BC$, $AC$, and $AB$, respectively. Let $D$ be the reflection of $P$ around $X$. Similarly, define $E$ and $F$. Denote $U$, $V$, and $W$ as the midpoints of sides $BC$, $AC$, and $AB$, respectively. Let $D'$ be the reflection of $D$ around $U$. Similarly, define $E'$ and $F'$. Then:

> $$[DEF] + [D'E'F'] = [ABC],$$

where $[]$ denotes areas.

For some time, I've been contemplating the idea that there might be an analogous/extended version of this theorem related to tetrahedra. Today, I conducted some experiments using Geogebra and a [volume calculator](http://tamivox.org/redbear/tetra_calc/index.html?fbclid=IwAR1sUfPBKVURhWckkRlCMM0geuQjsyiBB0NxHlOsDW5wgTR80zAFfRylzHo) that utilizes the matrix formula. Based on my findings, I arrived at the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture**: Let $ABCD$ $(T_1)$ be any tetrahedron with vertices lying on a sphere, and $P$ be an arbitrary point in space. Denote $G_{ABC}$ as the centroid of the face $ABC$, and $Q_{ABC}$ as an arbitrary point inside $ABC$ and lying in the same plane. Let $P'_{ABC}$ be the reflection of $P$ with respect to $Q_{ABC}$. Similarly, define $P'_{ABD}$, $P'_{ACD}$, and $P'_{BCD}$. Let $T_2$ be the tetrahedron defined by these four points. Now, denote $P''_{ABC}$ as the reflection of $P'_{ABC}$ with respect to $G_{ABC}$. Analogously, define $P''_{ABD}$, $P''_{ACD}$, and $P''_{BCD}$, and let $T_3$ be the tetrahedron defined by these points. Then:
> $$V_2 + V_3 = V_1,$$

where $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ denote the volumes of $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$, respectively.

The proof I have in mind uses analytic geometry and the matrix formula. I know how to find the coordinates of the centroids and the reflected points, but I have no idea how to parameterize the arbitrary points $Q$ on the faces of the tetrahedron. Could someone confirm whether this conjecture is true?

Comment: This is related to a [previous question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435812/looking-for-the-3d-analog-extension-of-a-2d-theorem).

Comment: Wait, wait, wait ... This has nothing to do with promoting trig's half-angle formulas. Who are you, and what have you done with the real Emmanuel José García?

Comment: @Blue: There is an overwhelming number of theorems (including the most astonishing ones) in classical geometry whose constructions somehow obey certain symmetry, either by starting with midpoints, reflecting points or lines, etc. Symmetry is a central concept in physics, and this centrality seems to be reflected in mathematics as well. I believe that the explanatory power of the half-angle formulas roots in symmetry. Therefore, I think that both this conjecture (hopefully true) and the half-angle formulas are distinct manifestations of the fruitfulness of symmetry. But this is just an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the conjecture is false for tetrahedra.
$$A (8.81677261342614, -5.95109812523592, 0.00000000000000)\\
B (-0.868026162586332, 6.82346541589857, 0.00000000000000)\\
C (6.99038460398954, 4.45229870144277, 1.56030015466736)\\
D (0.987740774325822, 1.98714940900149, 4.02997763720348)$$
**Volume: 58.01800458**

$$P'ABC (8.81867941456366, 15.3602994734030, 1.05673420386347)\\
P'ABD (11.5702309614861, 5.30685185335826, 1.70376656686520)\\
P'ACD (10.1012477803281, 10.7579977259050, 5.40704749520762)\\
P'BCD (6.18230217961132, 14.1245366398754, 5.51507484080838)$$
**Volume: 20.37474752**

$$P''ABC (1.14074128865590, -11.8105221453327, -0.0165341007519011)\\
P''ABD (-5.61257281137571, -3.40050738691550, 0.982885191270448)\\
P''ACD (1.09535088083288, -10.4324310690995, -1.68019563396039)\\
P''BCD (-1.44223603579196, -5.28259428898019, -1.78822297956115)$$
**Volume: 3.02160658**